# Java Jython license - lack of understanding

Tags: java, jython, licensing, notice

I have read Jython license information available here http://www.jython.org/license.html and I'm not quite sure how to adapt to this points in the license guide:

1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

I suppose that second point means that I should attach license.txt file with my program when I want to release it to public? Is that true?

But I'm not sure at all how could I adjust to the first point. Should I write in my program a piece of code which show up a popup window with copied license text? And this popup window should appear every time user run my program? Or maybe just once?

And what could happen when I don't follow by this steps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a licensing question.

Comment: You could try [Open Source Stack Exchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/). Questions about Open Source licensing are specifically on topic there.

Comment: <biasedme>They are totally on-topic! Thanks @BoristheSpider!</biasedme>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

point#1 means, you need to retain the licensing agreement and copyright notice on each and every source file/binary files. Also, you need to include the copyright and licensing agreement as it is along with your own licensing agreement.

[Disclaimer: This is my own understanding, this doesn't constitute any legal opinion.]

In case of any doubt, it's always worth checking with the owners.